# What will happen if I won't clear stringstream?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I was doing a graph problem in TopCoder and somehow my program kept outputting wrong answer even though I thought everything should be ok with it. I spent hours and hours looking for error in my logic and, as it turned out, the problem was lying somewhere else. Here is a snippet of code I've got a question about:

```
int x, y;
stringstream ssx;
stringstream ssy;
for (int i = 0; i < connects.size(); i++){
    neighbours.push_back(vector<int> ());
    edges_cost.push_back(vector<int> ());
    ssx.str(connects[i]);
    ssy.str(costs[i]);
    while (ssx >> x && ssy >> y){
        neighbours[i].push_back(x);
        edges_cost[i].push_back(y);
    }
    // The problem lied here. Apparently without these 2 lines
    // the program outputs wrong answer. Why?
    ssx.clear();
    ssy.clear();
}
```

As you can see in the comments I managed to solve the problem. But I can't see why do I need to clear those stringstreams. What exactly is happening if I'm not doing that?

Comment: By the time you reach the end of the `while` loop, the eof bit (or another error bit, depending on your input) is set on the stream, which causes all subsequent operations to fail unless you clear it.

Comment: Of course, as currently written, the streams go out of scope without any action performed anyway so I don't see why this would matter.  I guess some relevant code might be missing.

Comment: @5gon12eder: The code _clearly_ sets the stream buffer and extracts from it during each loop iteration...

Comment: @T.C. Please do not write answers in comments. This behaviour seems to be in vogue at the moment but it's a definite anti-pattern. Comments are for requesting clarification and berating people.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're right – parsing error on my behalf.  Removed extraneous indentation to save others the trouble of making the same mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you've extracted all data from the stream and attempted to read "just one more character!" (which the in-built extraction to `int` will try to do, to find out whether there are more digits to read), its `eof` bit is set.

You are re-using the stream by changing its buffer's "contents", which is fine, but you need to reset that `eof` bit too. That's what `.clear()` does.

To re-use a stringstream in general:

```
ss.str("");  // clears data
ss.clear();  // clears all error flag bits
```

*(In your case you're directly replacing the buffer with your new data, later on, using `.str("newText!")`, instead of writing `.str("")`, and that's fine.)*

It's confusing because a function like `clear` *sounds like* it's going to clear the data, but it doesn't.